# Need help on creating Shopping Cart Rule for Specific Brand and of Fixed Value with Minimum Shopping Value of that Brand

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

For example INR 100 off on purchasing a item of XYZ brand of value 500 and above. I have Brand as an Attribute.

In the Cart there is 1 item of ABC Brand, 1 item of EFG Brand and 2 Items of XYZ Brand. Currently it is getting calculated on cart subtotal hence calculation is going wrong.

Ideally this should be considered on the line item total of the cart which have XYZ as a Brand. Don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

On "**Conditions**" tab

add this condition:

```
If total amount  greater than  500  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
Manufacturer  is  XYZ
```

On "**Action**" tab under "**Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)**" set:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Manufacturer  is  XYZ
```

Apply **Percent of products price discount**

Discount Amount  **your choise**

Comment: Thank you so much appreciate, appreciate your help, can u please help me with the same condition but instead of fixed amount discount I, how do I set a % discount for XYZ Brand. I edited the action piece and converted from "fixed amount discount for whole cart" to "% of product price discount" and its not working. It take the % discount for whole cart and not for the brand XYZ only.

Comment: I've edited the answer.